# How to create(update) file in GitHub repo using GitHub API and Python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, github-api

I'm creating a new file in GitHub public repo using python. 
When I try to do this:

```
import json
import requests

with open('README.md', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    payload = {"message": "Add text.txt",
               "author": {"name": name,"email": email},
               "content": content}
    result = requests.put("https://api.github.com/repos/<GitHubLogin>/<Repo>/contents/README.md", 
                           auth=(name, password), 
                           json=payload)
    print(result.json())
```

I get "{'message': 'content is not valid Base64', ....}"

If I try to do this:

```
import base64 
import json
import requests

with open('README.md', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = bytes(content, "utf-8")
    contnet = base64.b64encode(content)
    payload = {"message": "Add text.txt",
               "author": {"name": name,"email": email},
               "content": content}
    result = requests.put("https://api.github.com/repos/<GitHubLogin>/<Repo>/contents/README.md", 
                          auth=(name, password), 
                          json=payload)
    print(result.json())
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
     19     result = requests.put("https://api.github.com/repos/VadymKhodak/tester/contents/README.md", 
     20                           auth=(name, password),
---> 21                           json=payload)

TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

How to solve that issue?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Per the comments, doesn't seem like the below solution works.

Comment: Figured it out [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863293/python-github-rest-api-problems-with-the-update-file-contents-request/73875102#73875102)

Answer (score -1):

I solve this issue!!!

```py
ENCODING = 'utf-8'
with open('README.md', 'rb') as f:
    byte_content = f.read()
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(byte_content)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode(ENCODING)
    payload = {"message": "Add text.txt",
               "author": {"name": name,"email": email},
               "content": base64_string}
    result = requests.put("https://api.github.com/repos/<GitHubLogin>/<Repo>/contents/README.md", 
                          auth=(name, password), 
                          json=payload)
    print(result.json())
```

Comment: when trying the above, I get {'message': 'Not Found', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3'}

Comment: I get the same error message. Works if I use pyGitHub instead but would rather use requests.