# Python + Github REST API: Problems with the Update File Contents request

Tags: rest, python-requests, github-api

I'm getting a Status 400 from the [Update File Contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) Github API even though 400 isn't on the list of possible [HTTP response statuses!](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents--status-codes)

My problem is that the `content` key needs to be base64 encoded. But when I convert the content to base64, the API responds with "Problems parsing JSON" error.

Feels like it has something to do with the `f` strings. If I remove them and use the variable names, the request fails with the same error.

**How do I successfully submit this response?**

```py
def convert_to_base64(md_payload):
    encoded_payload = base64.b64encode(md_payload.encode('utf-8'))
    return encoded_payload

def log_todo(username, repo_name, filename, api_key, sha, encoded_payload):
    response= requests.put(
        f'https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo_name}/contents/{filename}',
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'
        },
        data = {
            "sha": f'{sha}',
            "message": "TEST",
            "committer": {
                "name": "TEST",
                "email": "test@test.rocks"
            },
            "content": f'{encoded_payload}'
        }
    )
    logging.error(f'##### Was TODO Logged in VCS?: {response.text}')
    return response.status_code
```

**Results:** There is nothing about this message nor the status 400 on the `doc_url`

```json
{
    "message":"Problems parsing JSON",
    "documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"
}

400
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

1. **Changed `convert_to_base64` function to:**

   - I have no idea why one has to encode to base64 then decode it, but this worked

```py
def convert_to_base64(md_payload):
    encoded_payload = base64.b64encode(md_payload.encode('utf-8'))
    encoded_payload = encoded_payload.decode('utf-8')
    return encoded_payload
```

2. **Changed the `data` parameter to `json`**

```py
def log_todo(username, repo_name, filename, api_key, sha, encoded_payload):
    response= requests.put(
        f'https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo_name}/contents/{filename}',
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}'
        },
        json = {                       #<--This is all I changed
            "sha": f'{sha}',
            "message": "TEST",
            "committer": {
                "name": "TEST",
                "email": "test@test.rocks"
            },
            "content": f'{encoded_payload}'
        }
    )
    logging.error(f'##### Was TODO Logged in VCS?: {response.text}')
    return response.status_code
```